# CSS: 1) how to make height of float element not affected by child element? 2) how to specify min-height on an element with float?

Tags: html, css, css-float

So, I have been searching for the answer for a day, but I still do not get the answer. I am not very good at CSS.

## The Case

I want to create 2 equal square (1:1 ratio) side-to-side (100% width) with a little bit of margin. Inside of the square, there are smaller square(s). The  `min-height` of the big square should be the width of the big square.

---

## What I have done

### The big square

I have done the big square, and It  look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyAUH.png). Even though it looks square, it is not. The ratio is still not 1:1. What is the best approach to fix this?

### The small square

I have tried, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAF4M.png) is the result. The quantity of the small square should not affect the height of its parent. What should I do to fix this?

---

## The code

`.html`:

```
<head>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <big-box id="left-box" style="background: blue;">
        <small-box style="background: white">
            <div>test</div>
        </small-box>
    </big-box>

    <big-box id="right-box" style="background: green;"></big-box>

</body>
```

`.css`:

```
big-box {
    background: pink;
    padding: 0.5% 0.5% calc(48% - 4px) 0.5%;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    width: calc(48% - 4px);
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

small-box {
    padding: 6%;
    float: left;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin: 1%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
}

big-box div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to use: aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; – the padding gives all the headache, as margin for the small box would not change the bounding box

```
.big-box {
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
background: pink;
color: white;
float: left;
margin: 2px;
position: relative;
width: calc(48% - 4px);
}

.small-box {
align-items: center;
aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
background: #f1f1f1;
color: black;
display: flex;
float: left;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0.5% 0.5% calc(48% - 4px) 0.5%;
/* margin: 1%; */
padding: 6%;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the properties inside CSS selector is sorted. Are you using some CSS extension?

Comment: on the mac there are so called services, which you can install. I use Wordservice from DEVONtechnologies which can be configured with a keyboard-shortcut, so I avoid headaches watching code, every class or id is sorted. there are exceptions where you need an attribute needs to go to the last line, but for the most time sorted attributes are easier to work with.